Tanstack React Query useMutation always True in onSuccess
import { TNewServicesProps } from '@/_constants/types';
import api from '@/_libs/api';
import { useMutation, useQueryClient } from '@tanstack/react-query';

const useManageServices = (
    method: 'create' | 'update' | 'delete',
    item_id?: number | string,
    values?: TNewServicesProps
) => {
    if ((method === 'update' || method === 'delete') && item_id == null) {
        throw new Error(`item_id is required for ${method} method`);
    }

    const queryClient = useQueryClient();
    const { data, error, isPending, mutateAsync, isSuccess } = useMutation({
        mutationKey: [`${method}_services`],
        mutationFn: async () => {
            switch (method) {
                case 'create':
                    return await api
                        .post(
                            `/admin/services/`,
                            JSON.stringify(values !== undefined ? values : {})
                        )
                        .then((res) => res.data)
                        .catch((error) => error.response.data);
                case 'update':
                    return await api
                        .patch(
                            `/admin/services/${item_id}/`,
                            JSON.stringify(values !== undefined ? values : {})
                        )
                        .then((res) => res.data)
                        .catch((error) => error.response.data);
                case 'delete':
                    return await api
                        .delete(`/admin/services/${item_id}/`)
                        .then((res) => res.data)
                        .catch((error) => error.response.data);
                default:
                    throw new Error(`Invalid method: ${method}`);
            }
        },
        //this is always fired, even when response code is 400, 500, etc.
        onSuccess: () => {
            queryClient.invalidateQueries({
                queryKey: ['services'],
            });
        },
                onError: () => {
                //should do something but never fired
                },
    });

    return { data, error, mutateStatus: mutateAsync, isPending, isSuccess };
};

export default useManageServices;


I'm currently experimenting with react-query in my project.
I'm facing an issue with error handling within my mutation.
When I check the network tab, I can see that the server responds with either a 400 or 500 status code, which I assumed would cause axios to throw an error, triggering the defined onError function.
However, the onSuccess function is always invoked.
What could I be overlooking? Thanks in advance.

I suspect the issue here is that your mutation function is catching the thrown errors before the useMutation hook can handle them to actually invoke any provided onError handler.
I suspect you could either not catch them at all, or simply re-throw them after they have been handled.
const { data, error, isPending, mutateAsync, isSuccess } = useMutation({
  mutationKey: [`${method}_services`],
  mutationFn: async () => {
    switch (method) {
      case 'create':
        return await api
          .post(
            "/admin/services/",
            JSON.stringify(values !== undefined ? values : {})
          )
          .then((res) => res.data);

       case 'update':
         return await api
           .patch(
             `/admin/services/${item_id}/`,
             JSON.stringify(values !== undefined ? values : {})
           )
           .then((res) => res.data);

       case 'delete':
         return await api
           .delete(`/admin/services/${item_id}/`)
           .then((res) => res.data);

       default:
         throw new Error(`Invalid method: ${method}`);
    }
  },
  onSuccess: () => {
    queryClient.invalidateQueries({
      queryKey: ['services'],
    });
  },
  onError: () => {
    // ...
  },
});

const { data, error, isPending, mutateAsync, isSuccess } = useMutation({
  mutationKey: [`${method}_services`],
  mutationFn: async () => {
    switch (method) {
      case 'create':
        return await api
          .post(
            "/admin/services/",
            JSON.stringify(values !== undefined ? values : {})
          )
          .then((res) => res.data)
          .catch((error) => {
            // error.response.data
            throw error;
          });

      case 'update':
        return await api
          .patch(
            `/admin/services/${item_id}/`,
            JSON.stringify(values !== undefined ? values : {})
          )
          .then((res) => res.data)
          .catch((error) => {
            // error.response.data
            throw error;
          });

      case 'delete':
        return await api
          .delete(`/admin/services/${item_id}/`)
          .then((res) => res.data)
          .catch((error) => {
            // error.response.data
            throw error;
          });

       default:
         throw new Error(`Invalid method: ${method}`);
    }
  },
  onSuccess: () => {
    queryClient.invalidateQueries({
      queryKey: ['services'],
    });
  },
  onError: () => {
    // ...
  },
});


Thank you @Drew Reese, I've removed the catch block and it works well.

btw, I have another question here, just thinking if you can also help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78520883/how-can-i-implement-the-functionality-to-post-reels-shorts-video-to-all-social-m

@RonaldVergelDelaCruz That post appears to be asking for recommendations for a library or package that can handle social media postings which is off-topic as being subjective, or is asking how to implement it all manually... without any specific details, which is too broad and open-ended and doesn't fit our Q and A format well, e.g. asking a question about a specific issue or problem with an exact/specific expected outcome/goal. I think it needs quite a bit more focus and objectivity to be better received on this site.

Just like @Drew Reese's answer mentioned you're prematurely capturing the error when react query is already doing it. I think a simplified version of your code might be easier to see the issue.
mutationFn: async () => {
  const response = await api
    .delete(`/admin/services/${item_id}/`)
    .then((res) => { return res.data })
    .catch((error) => {
      // you're catching the error and returning the error response
      return error.response.data
    }
  return response; // this will be error.response.data, mutationFn doesn't fail, thus call the onSuccess function.
}

